# React useRef working fine but error in production?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

React Hook "useRef" is called in function "header" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWUzb.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error message is pretty straightforward. If `header` is a React component, its name should start with a capital letter:

```
const Header = () => {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shown error is not about useRef, you used it inside a wrong named react component header, should be named Header instead alway with an uppercase.